# JSON Object not being deserialized properly by Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, spring-boot

I am trying to make a post request with Axios to my api, but the JSON is not being deserialized properly into a java object, despite adding the `@ResponseBody` annotation. The field of the object are just `null`.

Here is my Controller:

```
@RestController
class WordSearchController {

    private long count;

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @PostMapping(
        value = "/word",
        consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}
    )
    public long Search (@RequestBody WordSearch wordsearch) {
        count = wordsearch.search();
        return count;
    }
}
```

Here is my axios.post call in handleSubmit:

```
class SubmitForm extends Component {
state = {
    sentence: '',
    word: '',
};
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.sentence);
    const user = {
        sentence: this.state.sentence,
        word: this.state.word,
    }
    console.log(user)
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/word', {user})
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
            console.log(res);
        })
}
```

Here is WordSearch.java:

```
public class WordSearch {

@JsonProperty("sentence")
private String sentence;
@JsonProperty("word")
private String word; 

public void setSentence(String sentence) {
    this.sentence = sentence;
}

public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}

public String getSentence() {
    return this.sentence;
}

public String getWord() {
    return this.word;
}

public long search() {
    Pattern word_pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b" + (this.word) + "\\b");
    Matcher countWord = word_pattern.matcher(this.sentence);
    long count = countWord.results().count();
    /* int count = 0;
    String [] words = (this.sentence).split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if ((words[i]).equals(this.word)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    */
    return count; 
}
```

}

The Payload appears as `{sentence: "hello", word: "world"}`

Comment: Please show your object class and payload.

Comment: Updated with object class and payload

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this:
`axios.post('http://localhost:8080/word', {user})`
be like this:
`axios.post('http://localhost:8080/word', user)`

Looks like user object is wrapped into another one.

Also, you can test with postman to see if the problem is on client or server side.